# Slim exit as username ends in black screen

Tags: arch-linux, slim

I recently installed Arch Linux on my notebook and it works fine.
But there is still one small problem. Following to the SLiM manual I can use `exit` to exit to the shell.

Unlike expected, I won't return to the shell, there is just a black screen where I cannot input anything. Also `ALT` + `F1`, `ALT` + `F2`, `ALT` + `F3` or `ALT` + `F4` makes no difference.

Do I need to configure anything? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SLiM#Shutdown.2C_reboot.2C_suspend.2C_exit.2C_launch_terminal_from_SLiM). 
If you still problems, you'll need to capture the log and put it into pastebin to show us:

```
tail -n 50 /var/log/slim.log
```

BTW. According to Arch Linux wiki, SLiM is outdated and upstream development has ceased

Comment: Which Login Manager would you recommend me then?

Comment: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager

Comment: I use **LXDM**, but may I recommend that you try [lightdm](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=40708)

Answer (score 1):

You said <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> wasn't doing anything but, to switch between consoles for me it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/etc., so that might have been the issue.